# RSpec: Named routes or hard coded URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In a Rails project, and in an RSpec spec file, what are the pros and cons for using a named route, such as `blogs_path()` vs a hard coded URL, such as `/blogs`?

I know the answer is highly opinionated, but it will help me (and many others) to get a view of the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: Named routes are there so you don't have to hardcode urls. That's the whole point of named routes. Hardcoding stuff is never a good practice for mantainability.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as with any hardcoded stuff: harder to change later.

If you change your path from `/blogs` to `/interesting_stuff_people_have_to_say` it's a one line change if you're using the methods (named routes):

```
 - get :blogs
 + get :blogs, as: :interesting_stuff_people_have_to_say
```

But if you hardcoded the path, you need to change it everywhere you used it. You might even miss some cases:

```
url = 'blog' + 's' 
redirect_to url
```

Which will cause your specs to fail (if you're lucky and have this covered) or errors on production.